# Replacing Div contents with results of an href click

Tags: php, ajax

Complete newbie but learning!

I have a php file presenting my menu ie

```
<li><a href="printers3.php" class="ajaxLink" name="Printer area" title="Printers3">Printers3</a></li>
```

and I am trying to include the output from printers3.php (the final line is echo $table; ) later on in the code within div id="MiddleColumnWrapper"

I have put the following code in my Head

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( ".ajaxLink" ).on( "click", function() {
        var ajaxUrl = $( this ).attr( "href" );
        $.get({
            ajaxUrl,
            function( response ) {
                $( "#MiddleColumnWrapper" ) .html( response );
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

But at the moment I just get the result of $table in a new window.
Have I missed something or just not on the right track?
Thanks

Top code bit of the linking script

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( ".ajaxLink" ).on( "click", function() {
        $.get({
            url : 'printers3.php',
            function( response ) {
                $( "#MiddleColumnWrapper" ) .html( response );
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="SiteWrapper">
<?php
    /* Output the header */
    include 'includes/header.php';
?> 

<div id="MiddleColumnWrapper">
<p>Middle column</p>
</div>
```